# Word for young mustache?

Tags: single-word-requests

How  in one word do you describe the soft, thin, first-time mustache that grows when a boy goes through puberty?

Tender? Immature?

Comment: 'Peach fuzz' is the phrase I've heard. 'Course, that's two words.

Comment: You mean one term, or one word?  What is this for that you need just a single word without spaces or hyphens in it?  The term  [“peach fuzz”](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/260734) is a single entry in the OED: **1.** Something resembling the down of a peach in texture; *esp.* soft facial hair, often that of an adolescent boy.

Comment: Just as an added angle, a popular Hebrew term for it is "Bar-Mitzvah moustache"

Comment: _Wispy_ and _scraggly_ come immediately to mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Peach fuzz](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/260734?redirectedFrom=peach%20fuzz#eid)*.  From OED:

> Chiefly N. Amer. (orig. U.S.).  A. n.
>
> 1. Something resembling the down of a peach in texture; esp. soft facial hair, often that of an adolescent boy.

Comment: Linking to the OED rather than Urban Dictionary would make this a better answer.

Comment: Didn't realize I could!

Answer (score 9):

When I had stuff like this on my upper lip it was referred to by my elders and (doubtless) betters as *[bum-fluff](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bumfluff)*.

Comment: Yes, that was certainly the word with which I was taunted.