# Meaning of the word "snood"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does actually *snood* mean when someone says, 'He is a *snood* arm wrestler. He eats more than he trains, but he's beaten some of our toughest guys.'
Does it mean that person who's called *snood* arm wrestler is kind of lazy to train hard and has some extra weight?
[Link to the video, I've heard that word there, at 54 second](http://youtu.be/bcTZlhmOkk0?t=54s)
The video is available only in USA.

Comment: I never heard the word used for anything except the (extra fine) length of fishing line between the hook and the main line (which is heavier, and more visible to the fish). Apparently it's also a woman's head/hair band, and sometimes a general-purpose meaningless pejorative noun. Perhaps akin to *nerd, dork*, so perhaps someone used it to mean *"This guy has no chance of picking up girls, so he puts all his energy into geeky activities such as arm-wrestling"*. Mostly it probably means whoever you heard using the word doesn't know or care much about how other people use English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know Snood as [something else entirely](http://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/snood/screenshots/gameShotId,109350/).

Comment: Maybe I didn't get it right, maybe there're some homonyms which sound similarly, but have different meaning, I'm not sure...

Comment: Please edit the video link into your question. It sounds to me like he's saying, “He’s’n’ood arm wrestler” and probably means “He’s a good....”

Comment: You're the second person who thinks so, probably you're right)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The video doesn't use the word "snood". The actual transcription should be:

> MAN 1: Turbo
>
> MAN 2: **He's new to** arm-wrestling.
>
> MAN 1: He eats more than he trains... but he's beaten some of our toughest guys.

The accent makes it a little hard to pick out that MAN 2 says arm-wrestling and not arm-wrestler because he chops off the "ing" sound to make a very "redneck" style *wrestlin'*. Likewise, the "to" is actually pronounced *tuh* or *ta* and the "he's" is very short and barely has the "he" portion. Altogether it sounds like:

> eeznooh tuh ahrm rasslin'
>
> 'e's new ta' arm-rasslin'
>
> he's new to arm-wrestling

"Snood" doesn't have a relevant meaning in this context and the speaker absolutely says "arm-wrestling" instead of "arm-wrestler".

Comment: FWIW, I lived in Texas for a few years. This is a fairly light "redneck" accent that can be found all over the southern United States. More info can be found on Wikipedia: [Southern American English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English)

Comment: MrHen, you was absolutely right. Yesterday I watched the full episode of the show and the same guy said similar phrase about Turbo 'He's new to this sport'.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone who clicked this question actually looking for the meaning of the word ***snood***: in my experience (and confirmed by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snood_%28headgear%29)), while it is a neck covering that can be raised over the head by women and/or motorcyclists, it can also be used to refer to a hairnet which is specifically used to cover a beard, in food production.

Comment: Avoiding wearing one was the main reason I opted to shave during my teenage years when I worked part time at a deli, rather than try to grow out my [bum fluff](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69380/word-for-young-mustache), for which I came to be most grateful in later years. Men really ought to shave for the first five years that they need to if they want to grow anything like a beard or moustache.

Comment: This is exactly the meaning of snood. I owned several snoods to protect my ears and head in cold weather. They were elegant looking and secure compared to a hat and scarf combination. Good answer!

Answer (score -1):

According to the "urban dictionary" it's just more-or-less meaningless substitute for "bad/unpleasant".

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=snood

The work also has several other meanings which do not apply here. For example, it's the flap of skin on a turkey's beak.

Another distinct possibility (purely conjecture) is that the speaker intended to say "good" and due to regional accents or slip of the tongue said "snood" (or something like it) instead.

Comment: Yeah, there is a bunch of various meainings, including "The ballsack thing that hangs off a turkey's face", I guess "bad/unpleasant" or in other words "snoob + rude" (how it's describes on urban dictionary) is more appropriate, but still makes me doubt...

Comment: @Lumberjack Some guy above said something like a "dork"; that seems fairly OK as well. I have my doubts too - perhaps you could tell us precisely where in the world you heard this - it might be regional slang.

Comment: I've heard it in promo-video of reality show. Maybe I got it wrong, but 2 friends of mine hear the same sound (word).

I got a link btw, but it works only within USA...
http://youtu.be/bcTZlhmOkk0?t=54s
from 54 second

Comment: @Lumberjack I have a theory... they said "good"... or they meant to - and they just stuffed it up a bit.

Comment: Good theory, these guys are from South of the USA, I've noticed they have special way of spelling some words =)

Comment: @Lumberjack I'm an on-and-off listener of infowars (Texas) and I can imagine AlexJ causing a similar confusion with his diction (very strong accents and lazy way of speaking). Not sure there's anything else I can do... all the best :)

Comment: I'm very greatful to you, my friend, thanx!)

Answer (score -1):

After listening to the video several times, it sounds to me like the speaker says, “He’s’n’ood arm wrestler,” in heavily accented American English. I doubt that this is the word *snood*; more likely it simply means “He’s a good arm wrestler” with a bit of an accent or quirk of speech. It's also possible that he tried to say, “He’s **an** ... arm wrestler” and stumbled over the words because *good* doesn't start with a vowel.